# How to get type from scope in template class?

Tags: c++11

Here I have some interesting code. Does anyone know how to get subtype from `myClass` without auxiliary parameter in template?

---

***Note:*** Maybe `myClass` template too.

```
class myClass
{
  public:
    struct tPacaje
    {
      int data;
    };
};

template <class T>
class executorClass
{
  public:
    void todo(T::tPacaje ob)
    {
      ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a type so need to tell the compiler you are using a `typename`:

```
template <class T>
class executorClass
{
  public:
    void todo(typename T::tPacaje ob)
    {
            //^-------
      //...
    }
};
```